# Blazor: Call Web API on property change

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm new to Blazor. Currently I have a problem when i tried to call Web API from Client side blazor app (Web assembly) and use checkbox in my UI as a filter of GET parameters.

Example:
I have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="chkOnlyActiveRecords" @bind="OnlyActiveRecords" @onclick="LoadDataFromServer" />
```

and API call:

```
@code {    

public bool OnlyActiveRecords{ get; set; }

private async Task LoadDataFromServer()
{
    data = await Http.GetJsonAsync<IList<Zeme>>($"Zeme?onlyActive={this.OnlyActiveRecords}");
}

}
```

Problem is that property OnlyActiveRecords contains old value at the moment of OnClick.

When I use onchange event like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="chkOnlyActiveRecords" @bind="OnlyActiveRecords" @onchange="LoadDataFromServer" />
```

I get error msg: "The attribute 'onchange' is used by the '@bind' directive attribute."

I there any way to call a method when value of property change in Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that @onchange is half of the @bind functionality, so you need to use 
 @bind-value="OnlyActiveRecords"  @onchange="LoadDataFromServer" 
 to separate the change event from setting the value.